# Promise being resolved immediately

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I need to retrieve data from multiple API calls and aggregate them with the click of a button in the UI. I need to print the data once they all have been executed fully. I am returning a Promise from the function that runs a for-loop to make all API calls in succession. I am also processing the API call results as I am receiving them. Hence I resolve the promise just outside that for-loop. (Reminder, the for-loop makes some API calls inside.) Now, when I call this function, the promise gets resolved immediately and the success function runs which basically gives me empty aggregate data which is not expected. Where/how should I resolve the promise in such case?

Basic structure of my code:

```
forLoopFunction(xyz)
  .then(function(){ // print aggregate data when successfull})
  .catch(function(){ // print couldn't retrieve data })


forLoopFunction(){

   return new Promise(resolve, reject){
     for(var i=0; i<...){
       api1_Call().$promise
         .then(
            api2_call().$promise
             .then(
               //work on aggregate data
            )
            .catch(reject(error))
         ).
        .catch(reject(error))
     }
     //end of for loop 
     resolve(aggregated_data);
 }
}
```

Edited code structure:

```
    //$scope.requests is populated before this function call, have seen it printed

    $scope.myFunc() 
        .then(function(result){console.log(result)})
        .catch(function(error){console.log("failed")})


    $scope.myFunc = function() {
            var promiseArray = [];
            for(var i=0; i<$scope.requests.data.length; i++) {
                promiseArray.push(new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {                                                                 
                        var requests= $scope.requests.data[i];                            
                        WorkflowsService.get({id: requests.key}).$promise
                            .then(
                                function (data)  {
                                    StepsService.query({workflowId: workflowData.id}).$promise
                                        .then(
                                            function (steps)  {                                            
                                            //some variables calculation
                                            var metadata = []; //this belongs to a single work request

                                            //some more values pushed to metadata array
                                            //switch case to calculate appropriate endpoint and system id    

                                            //$.ajaxSetup({async: false});
                                            $.ajax({
                                                url: apiEndpoint + systemId,
                                                type: 'GET',
                                                success: function(resp){                                                        
                                                    compartmentId = resp.compartmentId;                                                                                                                
                                                    $.get("/api/compartments/" + compartmentId, function (resp) {
                                                       //some values pushed to metadata
                                                    });
                                            },
                                            error: function(resp) {
                                                //put dummy data to metadata array
                                            }
                                        });

                                        //construct a URL to be pushed into metadata                                                                                                                                    
                                        $scope.metadataString += metadata.join("\n");                                                                                        
                                        Promise.resolve("resolved promise");
                                 })
                                 .catch( function(error){ Promise.reject("rejected"); console.log(error) } )
                            })
                            .catch( function(error){ Promise.reject("rejected"); console.log(error) } )                            
                    });
                    promiseArray.push(promiseObject);                        
             }                
            return Promise.all(promiseArray).then(function() { return $scope.metadataString; });
}
```

Comment: Can you create 2 seperate promises of these two api calls and resolve them in one go using Promise.all([array of your promises]) this will run all the computations parallely and resolve them in one go

Comment: Sorry, I made an answer because of my reputation I can't comment. As far as I know, for is a sync iterator, wich means, it won't wait until your promises resolve to start next loop. Perhaps you can check new for-await-of new feature to achieve what you want.

Comment: First you need to understand that your api calls are non-blocking.  So, the `for` loop runs to completion, starting all your API calls, then you call `resolve()`, then sometime a long time later, your api calls start to finish.  Thus, your call to `resolve()` has absolutely nothing to do with the results of  the api call because you call it before they were done.  I'd suggest an investigation (on your part) of `Promise.all()`.

Comment: Why are you turning `async` off?

Comment: I was trying to get that part executed synchronously for experimentation purpose. Removed it, but it did not solve my problem.

Comment: that second code block doesn't even parse - and inside the code block that does the `$.,ajax` - you don't wait for it to complete nor do you return anything from that .then ... in fact you have a bunch of `Promise.resolve` and `Promise.reject` calls that do absolutely nothing (because they are redundant, and you don't return them anyway)

Comment: you're also pushing a Promise that never rsolves/rejects `promiseArray.push(new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {` ... neither resolve nor reject are ever called - you also refer to some undefined variable `promiseObject` for no reason! and finally, your code indentation is over the top!

Comment: And what's supposed to be the result of all that code? What results are you trying to get out of it. If you're not going to focus on the real problem here and you just want to talk code structure, I will just give up and delete my answer because there's no way I can teach you the general topic of asynchronous programming in one answer here - that is not how stack overflow works. You could study an entire course or book on the general topic of asynchronous programming in Javascript. I can help you solve a SPECIFIC programming problem with real code.

Comment: The way you're adding metadata onto the end of `$scope.metadataString`, it even appears your operations have to be carefully sequenced in order (which your current attempt at a design does not do), but heck we don't know if that's true or not and that totally changes how you design a solution.  I've deleted my answer and will probably not participate more since this is such an incomplete question that there's no way to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

You should maintain promise for all `api` call then `resolve` all in one time which I am doing by using `promise.all`, this will give you data in `then` `callback` in the form of array of each `api` call.

```
forLoopFunction(xyz)
  .then(function(data){ console.log(data); // print aggregate data when successfull})
  .catch(function(){ // print couldn't retrieve data })


forLoopFunction(){
  var promiseArray = [];
     for(var i=0; i<...){
       var promiseObject =  new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
       api1_Call().$promise
         .then(
            api2_call().$promise
             .then(
               resolve(aggregated_data);
            )
            .catch(reject(error))
         ).
        .catch(reject(error))
        });
       promiseArray.push(promiseObject);
     }
   return Promise.all(promiseArray)
}
```

Comment: This is a major anti-pattern.  There is no reason to wrap one promise in another like this.

Comment: It didn't make a difference. Is there a way to see whether promises are being resolved or in progress? If I just keep waiting, the console doesn't print anything but the core logic is done running without falling into any of the .catch() blocks already